# Select Row In RadGrid Button_Click

Tags: c#, radgrid

I am using RadGrid And I have LinkButton in its ItemTemplate. Onclick of this linkbutton want to select the row.Now My Problem is when I click on link button its get previous selected index instesd of the row which I have selected.Here is my code:

**aspx**

```
     <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridLeadHistory" runat="server" GridLines="None"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1090px" Height="200px" HeaderStyle-Width="120px"
                onitemdatabound="RadGridLeadHistory_ItemDataBound"   >
                <MasterTableView ShowHeader="true">
                    <Columns>
                         <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Note"  UniqueName="Note" HeaderText="Note">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="120px"><asp:Label ID="LabelHistoryNote" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Note") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonHistoryNote" runat="server" CommandName="Select"  Text="Note" OnCommand="ButtonHistoryNote_Click" CssClass="buttonsmall" ForeColor="Red" /></td></tr></table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings>
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true"  />
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                </ClientSettings>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
     protected void ButtonHistoryNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "";
      foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridLeadHistory.SelectedItems)
      {
         
              Label lb  =(Label)item.FindControl("LabelHistoryNote");
              str = lb.Text;
          
      }
      string str2 = str;
      TextBoxShowNote.Text = str;
     
    }
```

Now My Problem is When I click on LinkButton It Selects the last row I have selected not the current one.How Can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I get answer ,I use CommandName property in Button and use select command,I change my code from button click event to SelectedIndex_Change event of RadGrid and Problem Solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in place of your For-loop:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridLeadHistory.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    Label lb = item["LabelHistoryNote"].Controls[1] as Label;
    str = lbl.Text;
}
```